# Link Arduino Uno to Particle Photon

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, softwareserial

I'm working on a prototype with a Particle Photon, but I've realized the required number of pins is bigger than the number of pins on my photon.

I thought I could have an Arduino Uno wired to some sensors, and link the Arduino to the photon via a Software Serial from the Arduino (as its serial pins will already be busy) to the Serial pins of the photon.

Is it possible, and is there a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: https://www.particle.io/

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to get more inputs you could use multiplexing. The multiplexing method is more robust than software serial will be. How to do this is explained [here](https://cityos.io/tutorial/1958/Use-multiplexer-with-Arduino) and [datasheet for the commonly used cd4051 here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4053b-mil.pdf)

You don't specify what kind of sensors you will use. if the sensors are i2c or similar it is possible to daisychain (multiplex too) them.

Answer (score -1):

Everything is possible, it is programming. People are doing software-only USB on AVRs.

I doubt that the effort is worth it, given how hard it is to debug such low-level code. Besides you can use on-board UART if you don't need the USB connectivity - just disable it.

Main question is - where is the main software run, aka "Who's the Brain"? If Photon, maybe you can use SPI? SPI is dead-simple to emulate in software.

Comment: The photon is the brain, the Arduino would provide me with more pins

Comment: The USB of the Photon will already be used, do I have options other than softSerial?

Comment: Photon has SPI. Arduino Uno has SPI.
Photon has I2C. Arduino Uno has I2C too.

Programming them will be easier than software emulation of UART. I'd try SPI.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this protocol. I'll definitely take a look!

Comment: I2C looks very interesting also, especially the fact that it uses only 2 pins and still works with a small voltage difference (5V vs 3.3V)

Comment: Yes, I2C is nice to wire, but it's relatively complex to program. SPI is simpler to program than UART, but requires more wires (4 vs 2).